# count value and back again to the beginning of the code when user input numbers

Tags: c

after the program count what use input, it will printout the value, and after it the program will ask to continue or not, and if i press 'Y' the programm will start from the beginning when user input number. the question is how to make the program back to the beginning if user press 'Y'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void VOne();
int main(void) {
  VOne();
  return 0;
}

void VOne() {
  int i,quiz,exer,test,Final,FV,back;
  char again;
  while (1) {

    printf("Input Value : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&quiz,&exer,&test,&Final );
    FV = 0.10+(0.10*quiz)+(0.15*exer)+(0.30*test)+(0.35*Final);
    printf("%d\n",FV );
    if (FV >= 75) {
      printf("You pass the this class\n" );
    }
    else {
      printf("You've to take this class again in the next term\n");
    }
    printf("You want to input again?\n'Y'or'N\n");
    scanf("%c ",&again );
    if (again == 'y') {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: You seem to already be doing that (just not breaking the loop when user presses N). Are you referring to the case where the user inputs capital Y?

Comment: @xing thank you,it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void VOne();
int main(void) {
  VOne();
  return 0;
}

void VOne() {
  int i,quiz,exer,test,Final,FV,back;
  char again;
  while (1) {

    printf("Input Value : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&quiz,&exer,&test,&Final );
    FV = 0.10+(0.10*quiz)+(0.15*exer)+(0.30*test)+(0.35*Final);
    printf("%d\n",FV );
    if (FV >= 75) {
      printf("You pass the this class\n" );
    }
    else {
      printf("You've to take this class again in the next term\n");
    }
    printf("You want to input again?\n'Y'or'N\n");
    scanf(" %c ",&again );
    if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y') {
      continue;
    }
    else break;
  }
  return;
}
```